# Aggregate only existing elements of array in MongoDB document

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have data stored in collections of mongodb documents as below.

```
{"_id":1536921044022.3953,
"flow":[
    {"_id":1536921044279.358,"y":0.1,"i":375,"t":33.1},
    {"_id":1536921044914.2346,"y":0.2,"i":310,"t":40.9},
    {"_id":1536921045548.5076,"y":0.3,"i":408,"t":32.9}],
"__v":0}
{"_id":1536921044053.3254,
"flow":[
    {"_id":1536921044229.358,"y":0.4,"i":375,"t":33.1},
    {"_id":1536921044954.2346,"y":0.5,"i":310,"t":40.9},
    {"_id":1536921045514.506,"y":0.6,"i":408,"t":32.9}],
    {"_id":1536921045245.5056,"y":0.7,"i":408,"t":32.9}],
    {"_id":1536921045549.3076,"y":0.8,"i":408,"t":32.9}],
"__v":0}
```

I want to aggregate the data in the flow field such that I get an array representing the average datapoint for the `$flow.y` value for each corresponding element. Given the data above, the result should be `[0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.7, 0.8]`. Note that each available `y` field of the flow array has been averaged across all documents. The two last elements of the second document are returned as `0.7`, `0.8` as they don't exist in the previous one. Therefore the average of existing entries is just those two values, not `0.35`, `0.4` as you might expect. If there were a third document with `0.12, 0.13` then the returned elements would be `0.41` and `0.465`.

I have been trying combinations of `$arrayElemAt`, `$elemMatch`, `$avg` as part of an aggregate pipeline but I can't seem to hit the correct syntax.

Here's my progress so far (nodejs):

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
  ModelName.aggregate([
    { $project: { pulse: { $objectToArray: { $arrayElemAt: ["$flow", i]} } } },
    { $unwind: "$pulse" },
    { $match: { "pulse.k": "y" }},
    { $group: { _id: "$pulse.k", 
              count: { $sum: 1 },
              average: { $avg: "$pulse.v" },
              total: { $sum: "$pulse.v" }}}
  ], function (err, result) {
    console.log(err, result);
    running.push(result[0].average);
  });
};
```

It will return an average for the `y` field of each subdocument element of each document. So it's getting there. The key hurdles left are removing the loop and negating arrays without matching elements. I imagine to accomplish the latter I'll have to keep a running count of existing array element and divide by that for each average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) with `includeArrayIndex` option which will give you the order in initial array and the you can `$group` by that value, try:

```
db.model.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$flow",
            includeArrayIndex: "index"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$index",
            value: { $avg: "$flow.y" }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { _id: 1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            values: { $push: "$value" }
        }
    }
])
```

Outputs: `{ "_id" : null, "values" : [ 0.25, 0.35, 0.44999999999999996, 0.7, 0.8 ] }`

Comment: That's incredibly useful stuff mickl. Thanks.